# renaming hidden extensions which was automatically added

Tags: windows, cmd, rename

I am trying to launch a script as mentioned in this link
https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera-dl

it needs a file coursera-dl.conf I created the file with required parameters.
A screenshot is shown below file as seen in windows explorer
[image: file as seen in windows explorer]

But when I list the file in command prompt in windows 10
I see the following name
coursera-dl.conf.txt the file was created using notepad and saved as text file.
So I think the .txt extension automatically got added to it.
[image: cmd screenshot of file name]

How can I rename this file to coursera-dl.conf from coursera-dl.conf.txt, so that I Can use with the github tutorial.

Comment: `ren coursera-dl.conf.txt coursera-dl.conf`?

Comment: in notepad save as `All Files (*.*)`, then no additional extension is added.

Comment: Let me give you a piece of advise: never hide your file extensions!

Comment: if you have multple `.conf.txt` files `for %%i in (*.conf.txt) do ren "%%i" "%%~ni"`